# How to handleText View and Images by click on single button by using array and switch case and i need code for previos button in Android

Tags: android, arrays, button, switch-statement

Geeks! i am beginner in Android...i am working on another activity of android in my app, in this activity i have total 10 views(7 text views + 2 image Button + 1 image view) and two image buttons (i.e next and previous) and i change all these 10 views at a time by click on single next button, i used array and switch case for changing text values and images the reason is that all tex values are different from each other but problem is that i used first of these values in it's UI .xml file and not included in array, that's why when i click back button then it can't shows first value of all these values. Secondly, by default i also want to invisible previous button when user at first views and when user click on next button once then both button will be show and again when user reached at third click then invisible next button, How i can do that? i am stuck at here and also i don't know correct code of my previous button (like increment --) that's why i didn't added here. if you understand what i want to do then edit my code or post new code with same functionality. your help will be appreciated.

```
  My Java Code:
  public class AlifPics extends Activity {
TextView text1;
TextView text2;
TextView text3;
TextView text4;
TextView text5;
TextView text6;
TextView text7;
ImageView img1;
ImageButton imgBut1;
ImageButton imgBut2;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.alif_pics);

    text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    text3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    text4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    text5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    text6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    text7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);

    img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imgBut1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    imgBut2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

}

// this Menu Button method goes to MainActivity
public void indexHuroof(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

 int counter = 1;

String[] textvalue1 = { "a2", "a3" };
String[] textvalue2 = { "b2", "b3" };
String[] textvalue3 = { "c2", "c3" };
String[] textvalue4 = { "d2", "d3" };
String[] textvalue5 = { "e2", "e3" };
String[] textvalue6 = { "f2", "f3" };
String[] textvalue7 = { "g2", "g3" };

int[] myImageViewList1 = new int[] { R.drawable.img2, R.drawable.img3 }; // 123
int[] myImageButtonList1 = new int[] { R.drawable.ibut2, R.drawable.ibut3 }; // 1,2,3
int[] myImageButtonList2 = new int[] { R.drawable.ibut5, R.drawable.ibut6 }; // 4,5,6

// my next ImageButton
public void nextClick(View v) {
    try {

        switch (counter) {
        case 1: // first click
            text1.setText(textvalue1[0]);
            text2.setText(textvalue2[0]);
            text3.setText(textvalue3[0]);
            text4.setText(textvalue4[0]);
            text5.setText(textvalue5[0]);
            text6.setText(textvalue6[0]);
            text7.setText(textvalue7[0]);
            img1.setImageResource(myImageViewList1[0]);
            imgBut1.setImageResource(myImageButtonList1[0]);
            imgBut2.setImageResource(myImageButtonList2[0]);
            break;
        case 2: // second click
            text1.setText(textvalue1[1]);
            text2.setText(textvalue2[1]);
            text3.setText(textvalue3[1]);
            text4.setText(textvalue4[1]);
            text5.setText(textvalue5[1]);
            text6.setText(textvalue6[1]);
            text7.setText(textvalue7[1]);
            img1.setImageResource(myImageViewList1[1]);
            imgBut1.setImageResource(myImageButtonList1[1]);
            imgBut2.setImageResource(myImageButtonList2[1]);
            break;
        case 3: // third click
            text1.setText(textvalue1[2]);
            text2.setText(textvalue2[2]);
            text3.setText(textvalue3[2]);
            text4.setText(textvalue4[2]);
            text5.setText(textvalue5[2]);
            text6.setText(textvalue6[2]);
            text7.setText(textvalue7[2]);
            img1.setImageResource(myImageViewList1[2]);
            imgBut1.setImageResource(myImageButtonList1[2]);
            imgBut2.setImageResource(myImageButtonList2[2]);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    counter++;
}

// my previous ImageButton
public void previousClick() {
    try {
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

as I get from your code my Sugests are:

1. Define your counter global and Static ( before OnCreate ) so the Value is reliable.
2. you can save all your text to the String.xml and your coding will be more beautiful and you can uese them like this:

   getResources().getString(R.string.yourString);
3. create a function to handle all must load string in on create like
       this:

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.alif_pics);

   ```
   preLoadText();
   initilizeUi();

   }

   void preLoadText(){

   // put all text stuffs

   }

   void initilizeUi(){

   // put you main application code

   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide your back imagebutton by adding this to ur oncreate method:

```
imgBut1.setEnabled(false);
imgBut1.setClickable(false);
```

Secondly, you can store the default values in the strings.xml file in the /res/values/ folder of your project, so that you can retain the values later.

```
<string name="textview1_deafult">TextView1 Deafult value</string>
```

and you can add the following code to disable the back button when counter reaches zero:

```
// my previous ImageButton
public void previousClick() {
    try {
        imgBut1.setClickable(false);
        imgBut1.setEnabled(false);
        text1.setText(R.string.textview1_default);
        //and so on
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

dont forget to use "string" with a lowercase "s" "R.string.textview1_default"

Comment: Kenji and @gkapagunta: can you send me the code plz?

Answer (score 0):

```
My Java Code:
public class AlifPics extends Activity {
TextView text1;
TextView text2;
TextView text3;
TextView text4;
TextView text5;
TextView text6;
TextView text7;
ImageView img1;
ImageButton imgBut1;
ImageButton imgBut2;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.alif_pics);

text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
text3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
text4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
text5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
text6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
text7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);

img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
imgBut1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
imgBut2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
//considering imgBut1 is back button and imgBut2 is next button
imgBut1.setEnabled(false);//disable back button at start
imgBut1.setClicakble(false);
}   

// this Menu Button method goes to MainActivity
public void indexHuroof(View v) {
Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
}

int counter = 1;

String[] textvalue1 = { "a2", "a3" };
String[] textvalue2 = { "b2", "b3" };
String[] textvalue3 = { "c2", "c3" };
String[] textvalue4 = { "d2", "d3" };
String[] textvalue5 = { "e2", "e3" };
String[] textvalue6 = { "f2", "f3" };
String[] textvalue7 = { "g2", "g3" };

int[] myImageViewList1 = new int[] { R.drawable.img2, R.drawable.img3 }; // 123
int[] myImageButtonList1 = new int[] { R.drawable.ibut2, R.drawable.ibut3 }; // 1,2,3
int[] myImageButtonList2 = new int[] { R.drawable.ibut5, R.drawable.ibut6 }; // 4,5,6

// my next ImageButton
public void nextClick(View v) {
try {

    switch (counter) {
    case 1: // first click
        text1.setText(textvalue1[0]);
        text2.setText(textvalue2[0]);
        text3.setText(textvalue3[0]);
        text4.setText(textvalue4[0]);
        text5.setText(textvalue5[0]);
        text6.setText(textvalue6[0]);
        text7.setText(textvalue7[0]);
        img1.setImageResource(myImageViewList1[0]);
        imgBut1.setImageResource(myImageButtonList1[0]);
        imgBut2.setImageResource(myImageButtonList2[0]);
        imgBut1.setEnabled(true);//enable back button
        imgBut1.setClickable(true);
        break;
    case 2: // second click
        text1.setText(textvalue1[1]);
        text2.setText(textvalue2[1]);
        text3.setText(textvalue3[1]);
        text4.setText(textvalue4[1]);
        text5.setText(textvalue5[1]);
        text6.setText(textvalue6[1]);
        text7.setText(textvalue7[1]);
        img1.setImageResource(myImageViewList1[1]);
        imgBut1.setImageResource(myImageButtonList1[1]);
        imgBut2.setImageResource(myImageButtonList2[1]);
        break;
    case 3: // third click
        text1.setText(textvalue1[2]);
        text2.setText(textvalue2[2]);
        text3.setText(textvalue3[2]);
        text4.setText(textvalue4[2]);
        text5.setText(textvalue5[2]);
        text6.setText(textvalue6[2]);
        text7.setText(textvalue7[2]);
        img1.setImageResource(myImageViewList1[2]);
        imgBut1.setImageResource(myImageButtonList1[2]);
        imgBut2.setImageResource(myImageButtonList2[2]);
        imgBut2.setEnabled(false);
        imgBut2.setClickable(false);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
}
counter++;
}

// my previous ImageButton
public void previousClick() {
   switch (counter) {
    case 4: 
        text1.setText(textvalue1[1]);
        text2.setText(textvalue2[1]);
        text3.setText(textvalue3[1]);
        text4.setText(textvalue4[1]);
        text5.setText(textvalue5[1]);
        text6.setText(textvalue6[1]);
        text7.setText(textvalue7[1]);
        img1.setImageResource(myImageViewList1[1]);
        imgBut1.setImageResource(myImageButtonList1[1]);
        imgBut2.setImageResource(myImageButtonList2[1]);
        imgBut2.setEnabled(true);
        imgBut2.setClickable(true);
        break;
    case 3: 
        text1.setText(textvalue1[0]);
        text2.setText(textvalue2[0]);
        text3.setText(textvalue3[0]);
        text4.setText(textvalue4[0]);
        text5.setText(textvalue5[0]);
        text6.setText(textvalue6[0]);
        text7.setText(textvalue7[0]);
        img1.setImageResource(myImageViewList1[0]);
        imgBut1.setImageResource(myImageButtonList1[0]);
        imgBut2.setImageResource(myImageButtonList2[0]);
        break;
    case 2: 
        text1.setText(R.string.textview1_default);
        text2.setText(R.string.textview1_default);
        text3.setText(R.string.textview1_default);
        text4.setText(R.string.textview1_default);
        text5.setText(R.string.textview1_default);
        text6.setText(R.string.textview1_default);
        text7.setText(R.string.textview1_default);
        img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_default_drawable_for_img1);
        imgBut1.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_default_drawable_for_imgBut1);
        imgBut2.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_default_drawable_for_imgBut2);
        imgBut1.setEnabled(false);
        imgBut1.setClickable(false);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
}
counter--;
}
```

This should do the trick

Comment: gkapagunta: by applying your above code my previous button is still not working and also i have one confusion is that in previous button i place counter++ or counter-- ?

Comment: gkapagunta : it's enable to post my code again, it's showing me error of too long characters, how i send you my code, i need your help.